# Android exclude e.g. Neuxs 7 and Nexus 10 in PlayStore

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to exclude e.g. the Nexus 7 and Nexus 10 from installing my app (with the PlayStore), so I added following entry into the manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

The problem is, that the PlayStore still shows it as compatible.

Answer (score 0):

according to developer documentation [from the documnets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

```
<!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
...
```

you can specify the all configurations here

Comment: But this way e.g. the LG G3 (D855) would be excluded. So I also need to add screenDensity -> 480, 560 and 640. But how can I be sure, that I do not disable other phones?

Comment: So, to restrict the app installation to certain device when you upload APK at market , you need to do this Applications->select your application->APK-> Supported devices | Excluded devices  from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429070/android-disable-to-install-app-on-tablets

Comment: That's the problem. The Nexus 7 and Nexus 10 are largeScreens and the PlayStore still allow it, but I excluded it in the manifest. I don't know why. And I don't want to exclude every single device manually, because I don't know what are "tablets" - I also know, that it would be better to support every screen size, but the customer doesn't want to.

Comment: Try adding the above snippet to your AndroidManifest.xml, and if Google Play includes 7" tablets in the supported devices list, you can always remove them. along with this snippet  <!-- large screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />