# Disable tablet or large screen support in Unity?

Tags: android, xml, unity-game-engine, apk

How can I disable tablet or large screen support when building for Android in Unity?

I don't see any options in Player settings.

Also, I've seen this question: [Android: Disable to install app on tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429070/android-disable-to-install-app-on-tablets)

I'm building my APK with Unity so I don't know how to edit my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a custom AndroidManifest.xml for Unity to use by placing one in the Assets/Plugins/Android folder.

If you make an Android build, a basic copy of this file, which you can use as a starting point for creating a custom version, is located in Temp/StagingArea. Note that this directory gets deleted when you exit Unity!

Answer (score 0):

Another update on this:

I found this little checkbox in the Android publish settings to use your own LauncherManifest.xml. Just use the replace tool to raise the priority when merging all manifests. The screenshots says it all:

[image]

---

Since this answer is quite old, here is a little update:

Since Unity 2019.3, the support-screens node is located in LauncherManifest.xml and its properties cannot be overridden by the self-defined properties. You'll get merge conflicts.

Have a look at the basics:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html

**So, what I did:**
There are more than 10 mainfest xml files in the temporary build folder and it was quite difficult to figure out which one to manipulate to get the correct settings in the final AndroidManifest.xml. So I wrote a small script that uses the IPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject interface and changes all the appropriate nodes. Then I removed unnecessary things and this is the result:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor.Android;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeSupportedScreens : IPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject
{
    public int callbackOrder { get { return 0; } }
    private List<string> _androidManifestPaths = new List<string>
    {
        "Temp/gradleOut/launcher/src/main",
        "Temp/gradleOut/unityLibrary/src/main",
    };

    private const string ANDROID_MANIFEST_FILENAME = "AndroidManifest.xml";

    public void OnPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject(string _)
    {
        foreach (var manifestPath in _androidManifestPaths)
        {
            var androidManifestPath = GetAndroidManifestPath(manifestPath);
            if (File.Exists(androidManifestPath))
            {
                var androidManifestXML = File.ReadAllText(androidManifestPath);
                androidManifestXML = ReplaceValue(androidManifestXML, "largeScreens", "true", "false");
                androidManifestXML = ReplaceValue(androidManifestXML, "xlargeScreens", "true", "false");

                File.WriteAllText(androidManifestPath, androidManifestXML);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Error: File {androidManifestPath} not found");
            }
        }
    }

    private static string ReplaceValue(string content, string key, string oldValue, string newValue)
        => content.Contains(key) ? content.Replace($"{key}=\"{oldValue}\"", $"{key}=\"{newValue}\"") : content;

    private static string GetAndroidManifestPath(string path)
    {
        var separator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        var manifestPath = path.Replace('/', separator);
        return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, $"..{separator}..{separator}{manifestPath}", ANDROID_MANIFEST_FILENAME));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. I double checked the result with the help of apktool to see what's going in the packed APK AndroidManifest.xml.
Of course you can use this snipped to override other values if the common method, using an own AndroidManifest.xml in Plugins/Android isn't working for you.

Disclaimer:

1. Used on a Windows Unity Editor
2. I know that parsing the string to a XML document might be better. I leave that to someone else.