# How can I test the 'uses:feature= telephony' requirement on an AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I asked a question earlier about stopping tablets from an android app and I've added this line to the code:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true"/>
```

Now I want to verify it and be sure that the app cannot run on a tablet by testing it on an emulator. However, it seems like this requirement is always met on emulators. Is there another way to go about testing it?

Comment: Skype will use the calling  intent as a normal phone. If you want to stop tablets, isn't there a "supports screens" element of the manifest you can add?

Comment: "Declared <uses-feature> elements are informational only, meaning that the Android system itself does not check for matching feature support on the device before installing an application. However, other services (such as Google Play) or applications may check your application's <uses-feature> declarations as part of handling or interacting with your application."

Comment: @cricket_007, it's tricky because there are some tablets that support SIM cards. What we actually want to do is prevent devices that do not support SIM cards from downloading the app.

Answer (score 1):

You do, with that line, block **all devices that do not have access to a SIM card** from installing from Google Play. This isn't limited to tablets. THere may be phones without sim cards, and there **are** tablets with SIM cards and the ability to send text messages and make calls.

From Ken Wong's comment on the question:

> Declared  elements are informational only, meaning that the Android system itself does not check for matching feature support on the device before installing an application. However, other services (such as Google Play) or applications may check your application's  declarations as part of handling or interacting with your application.

If you want to block tablets as a whole, that is basically impossible. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429070/android-disable-to-install-app-on-tablets) offers a possible solution using the supports screens tag, but this, AFAIK, only makes the app incompatible on Google Play. If it is installed from a third party (USB debugging, APK mirror, from an APK file, etc) it can be installed. Once again we are back to the compatibility issue. The supports-screens tag is the same as the required tag: It is informational. Those who respect the tag doesn't allow installs. From [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html):

> An application that does not support small screens will not be available for small screen devices from external services (such as Google Play)

Small screens is just an example. If the support for any screen size is set to false, it will not be available from external services. Installing the APK directly (apk install outside Google Play or from USB debugging) bypasses it.

In addition, there are phones with xlarge screens. (They are more phablets I think the term is, but they are still phones. Just large ones).

So to summarize:

- Using the required tag (should in theory) allow the app to install from third party sources, but Google Play shows it as incompatible. So USB debugging and APK installs (not from Google Play) allows install. Check for compatibility at runtime instead
- Attempting to prevent tablets from accessing the app is basically stupid. Tablets can have SIM cards as well, blocking tablets because they have a bigger screen is not a good idea. Checking for the SIM card instead is the best way.
- As for the emulator, AFAIK it would install in testing even though required is true. It will crash if you make calls to things it doesn't have. Have you checked to ensure the tablet emulator actually **doesn't have telephony access**?

> Now I want to verify it and be sure that the app cannot run on a tablet by testing it on an emulator. However, it seems like this requirement is always met on emulators. Is there another way to go about testing it?

Well, required (as mentioned in a comment) is informational. The device itself doesn't check the conditions in the manifest (required = true at least). Once it is installed, check at runtime for compatibility. The required = true tag prevents installs from Google Play on unsupported devices (it shows up as "incompatible").

(Unfortunately) apps have a tendency to get pirated and uploaded to APK mirrors and similar sites (I know this from experience). These sites aren't like Google Play, and ignore the `required = true` calls. The app can be installed from these sites even on incompatible devices. So the best way to avoid incompatible usage is to check if the device has telephony access at runtime.

For checking on Runtime, that is a big field. [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196833/android-device-phone-call-ability) for different solutions.

Comment: Thanks. My intention is actually to block all devices without access to a SIM card. Is there a way to test this?

Comment: Check the last linked question, it contains several solutions you can check at runtime. The `required` tag only blocks installs on Google PLay, meaning it can be bypassed. Checking at runtime if the device supports it is much harder to bypass.